# ejected create_react_app & build (production) css not working working correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have an application that was created from [create_react_app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) then ejected, with no modifications.

Everything works as expected when running the dev version.

Unfortunately when I do `npm run build` and run this via `serve -s build` my styles are not working.

The .css files are being found and compiled into a single minified version. But the problem is that the markup that is generated is having the class name prefixes changed to **'T-'** instead of the prefix in the compiled .css file. (i.e) MyApp-header is getting changed to T-header, but in the minified css file, it still refers to MyApp-header.

[prefix changed to T-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIOEC.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add your webpack.config.js to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be caused by some nuance of using this...

> [@SuitCssify.decorator](https://github.com/RallySoftware/react-suitcssify#es2015-class-with-a-decorator)

I was evaluating this library for potential use in a project, and didn't discover this issue until trying to produce an actual production build.

I've since abandoned this approach and changed my configuration to use "CSS Modules" which are working out great. I would provide a link, but my reputation only allows me one link per post. ;(

[my 'webpack.config.[dev & prod].js' changes to enable css modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXyII.png)